# How to fill an html table with data from both a database and an xlsx file using ASP Classic

Tags: excel, vbscript, asp-classic

What I want to do is to create an html table that displays data from both a database and an xlsx file using ASP Classic.

To make it clearer, column 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 will display data from the database and column 3 and 4 from the xlsx file. How can I achieve this?

These are my initial connections:

```
DB_STRING = "dsn=dsnName;UID=Id;pwd=pwd"
Set Connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connect.Open DB_STRING
Set RecSetOR01 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

ConnectXlsx = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=source; 
Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
```

I visualize that I somehow need  to combine the connections for a single query and then loop the recordset to the table, or?

Answer (score 0):

> Use the following code to display all data in html table format.

```
RecSetOR01.open "select * from table name",connect
response.write("<table border=1><tr><th>heading1</th><th>heading2</th></tr>")
while not(RecSetOR01.eof)
response.write("<tr><td>" & RecSetOR01("fieldname1") & "</td>")
response.write("<td>" & RecSetOR01("fieldname2") & "</td>")
response.write("<td>" & RecSetOR01("fieldname3") & "</td></tr>")
wend
response.write("</table>")
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your answer. Unfortunately it was not the one I was looking for. Your answer certainly helps with how I can set up the table but not how I can merge the data from the xlsx file with the data from the database before displaying them in the table

Answer (score 0):

Although it is a convoluted method, you could create a recordset on the fly and append 10 fields to it. You then loop through your database and 'AddNew' for each database recordset to fields 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
Then loop through your xlsx file and 'AddNew' for each cell to fields 3,4

You then would have a single recordset combining both pieces of data that you can loop through to create the rows in your table

Comment: Thank you for your help. I like this and I would have tried it out if I had known earlier :) 
How I solved it was by creating a temporary database table with my xlsx data and then join it with my database query. Thus I get all the data I need in one recordset and can loop it to my html table